# Data loss when converting byte to int on Arduino

Tags: c, types, arduino, bit-manipulation

I have a 3-byte array that buffers incoming bytes through the Serial port. Once it is full I want to use the bytes to call a function that takes a byte and an int as a parameter. This should theoretically not be a problem, but for some reason the bytes are not being converten into an int properly. Here is the code I have:

```
// for serialEvent()
uint8_t buffer[3] = {0, 0, 0};
uint8_t index = 0;

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    if (index > 2) {
      // buffer is full so process it
      uint16_t argument = (uint16_t)buffer[1];
      argument <<= 8;
      argument |= buffer[2];

      processSerial(buffer[0], argument);

      index = 0;
    }

    buffer[index] = Serial.read();

    index++;
  }
}

void processSerial(uint8_t action, uint16_t argument) { ... }
```

The problem appears to be in the line where the first bit is shifted to the left to make space for the second one. I have tried outputting the variable over the Serial port again and after the bit shift operation, it is 0.

The same thing happens when I try to replace the bit shift operation with a multiplication by 256 (which has the same result in theory).

Irritatingly, when I assign a static value like so, everything works fine:

```
uint16_t argument = 0x00CD;
argument <<= 8;
```

Is this a type cast problem? Am I missing something here?

Comment: `argument |= buffer[2];` You probably want buffer[0] here ?

Comment: Besides not doing the actual call with the 3 decoded bytes until the _4'th_ byte is available and not right away after the 3rd is received which would make sense, I can't see anything obviously strange.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I will rearrange the function a bit. The buffer indices are correct though.

Answer (score 0):

Have not found the solution as to why this happens, but using the word() function does exactly what I want:

```
uint16_t argument = word(buffer[1], buffer[2]);
processSerial(buffer[0], argument);
```

Annoyingly, it is defined as:

```
unsigned int makeWord(unsigned char h, unsigned char l) { return (h << 8) | l; }
```